# Add prometheus config for all jobs

Tags: prometheus

In my prometheus.yml I have several jobs defined like:

```
  - job_name: alpha
    scheme: 'https'
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - one.example
        - two.example
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '(.*).example.*'
        replacement: '${1}'
        target_label: 'slug'

  - job_name: beta
    scheme: 'https'
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - three.example
        - four.example
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '(.*).example.*'
        replacement: '${1}'
        target_label: 'slug'
```

as you can see, only the targets differ per job, all the other configs like `relabel_configs` and `scheme` etc. are the same. Because its not only two jobs but around 20 for now, I don't want to repeat the same settings for each job. Is there no way to create a default config for all jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to create a default config for all jobs?

No, there is no such way. `relabel_configs` are specified on the job level.

On the other hand, if all 20 of your jobs have exactly the same relabeling config, you might consider using a single job and additional labels for distinction (I assume you distinct right now by `job` label):

```yml
  - job_name: unitedjod
    scheme: 'https'
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - one.example
        - two.example
        labels:
          target_type: alpha
      - targets:
        - three.example
        - four.example
        labels:
          target_type: beta
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        regex: '(.*).example.*'
        replacement: '${1}'
        target_label: 'slug'
```

Here first group of targets will contain label `target_type` with value `alpha`, and second group - with value `beta`.